# Open app store directly in invitation mail

Tags: javascript, html, email

1. How to open app store in my mail? `window.location` not work in email. Is there a way not using redirect web page?
2. I use `navigator.userAgent` to distinguish Android and iOS, it seems not work in mail either.

Comment: You can't use any JavaScript in mail, for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Mobile Deep Linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_deep_linking).

Simply including the full URL for the App Store *should* enable the OS (either iOS, Android, Blackberry, etc) to work out the correct App to launch with the link.

Each OS has registered the base URL of the App Store with the corresponding App. You can even register your own App to be linked to certain base URLs if you like ([Android example code](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)).

So, for HTML emails, just include a `<a href=" URL to Store ">link</a>` (no javascript at all needed) and for Plain-Text emails, just the URL is needed. Then let the OS work out what to do next.

If you need to have a link for iOS and another for Android, just say something like:

*My Super Unicorn Star Fighter game is now available for `<a href="Apple link">iOS</a>` and for `<a href="Android link">Android</a>`*

This is a better solution because people can forward emails to their friends who may have a different device.